# Set timeout on zsh autocompletion

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh

I like ZSH's autocompletion feature, but often it hangs my terminal.

I'd like to set timeout on autocompletion so it cancels (kills) itself after *n* miliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to abort completions which take too long with `Ctrl-C`.

But (at least) in recent versions of zsh there seem to be some issues with aborting the completion under some circumstances. There is currently a discussion going on about that on the Zsh Workers mailing list [starting with this posting](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg01619.html).